# Анонимный класс

Tags: java, android

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Bitmap b = loadImageFromNetwork("http://example.com/image.png");
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

`Runnable()` это же интерфейс? Почему у него есть оператор `new`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что вы создаёте анонимный экземпляр класса, имплементирующего интерфейс `Runnable`, а не экземпляр самого интерфейса - и переопределяете метод `run()`.

А оператор `new` есть у `Runnable`, потому что он как и всё в Java наследуется от класса `Object`, то есть тоже является объектом, и также имеет 7 заветных методов :)

Но создать напрямую экземпляр интерфейса/абстрактного класса нельзя, можно лишь создать класс, наследуемый от них/имплементирующий их, и переопределить нужные методы.

В приведенном вами примере вы создаете анонимный класс, который имплементирует интерфейс `Runnable` - попробуйте просто создать `new Runnable()` - вылетит ошибка.

Comment: Я просто не полностью понимаю почему именно так пишут "new Runnable()". Ведь конструктор Thread вроде принимает в качестве параметра интерфейс, а мы получается... создаем класс(хоть и анонимный). Классы и функц. интерфейсы в данном случае взаимозаменяемы  как то ?

Comment: @АлексейБаскаков вы немного не поняли этот момент: конструктор `Thread` принимает экземпляр любого класса, имплементирующего интерфейс `Runnable`. Так делается часто, когда, например, вы хотите скрыть свою сущность и поделиться только некоторыми методами, передавая интерфейс. Так и в этом случае - `Thread`-у ничего не нужно, кроме интерфейса `Runnable`, потому он принимает любой класс, важно лишь чтобы он имел тот же функционал, что и `Runnable` - то есть, имплементировал этот интерфейс.

Comment: я понял, все что я хотел узнать... что происходит за "кулисами"... уже разобрался, что этой фразой компилятор создает  анонимный класс и имплементирует интерфейс указанный в параметрах метода(Runnable). Спасибо за ответ.